# Коллективная правка содержимого

Tags: поддержка, faq, правки

В первую очередь я бы хотел подчеркнуть всеобъемлющую цель проекта.

> Цель Stack Overflow на русском - стать лучшим местом в пространстве русского языка, где можно получить исчерпывающий ответ на содержательный вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию.

Задавая вопросы и отвечая на них, мы, сообщество, создаем дополнительную ценность, большую, чем просто помощь одному человеку - мы создаем единую базу прикладных знаний.

> Stack Overflow на русском призван сэкономить как можно больше человеко-часов за счет многократного использования готовых решений.

Помимо сугубо прикладной задачи, увеличения производительности работы IT-отрасли, проект несет дополнительную миссию - культурную. Мы меняем представление людей о способе общения в Рунете - оно должно быть доброжелательным, без унижения, ругани и спама, а также в рамках правил русского языка.

> Культурная миссия Stack Overflow на русском - вывести общение в Рунете на качественно новый уровень.

Для формирования своего поведения люди с давних времен привыкли полагаться на мнение знатоков. Уверен, среди пользователей Stack Overflow на русском много общественных деятелей, которые [влияют на тренды](http://goo.gl/d4vVht) всего Рунета.

**Задавая вопросы, отвечая на них, а также внося правки, мы вместе формируем новую культуру общения во всем пространстве русского языка.**

Культура нашего сообщества не просто шокирует новичков, она сбивает их с толку, становясь преградой для получения необходимых знаний. Причина ясна - пользователи, незнакомые со Stack Overflow на русском, просто не привыкли к цивилизованному профессиональному общению по делу на русском языке. Ошибки правописания, колкие шутки и нетематические ответы плотно засели в культуре публикации информации в Рунете.

Задача сообщества - непрерывно поддерживать уровень общения на высоком уровне.

1. **Удалять любое содержимое, не относящееся напрямую к тематике сообщества.** Stack Overflow на русском направлен на кристаллизацию знаний по программированию и системному администрированию. Вопросы задаются не только и не столько для пользователей, желающих ответить, а ответы даются не только и не столько для авторов вопросов - они публикуются для тысяч наших коллег, которые в будущем могут столкнуться с аналогичной проблемой. Задача сообщества сделать так, чтобы поиск решения проблемы занимал считанные секунды. Именно для этого мы составляем сообщения так, чтобы при прочтении пользователь мгновенно определял, является ли его задача аналогичной приведенной в вопросе, и еще быстрее вникал в имеющееся решения. При таком подходе любая информация, не относящаяся к теме вопроса, должна быть исключена с целью оптимизации времени коллег на прочтение проблемы и представленных решений.
2. **Вносить улучшающие правки в сообщения других участников.** Сконцентрировавшись на проблеме, случается, что мы упускаем какие-то детали оформления из виду. Такие недочеты особенно хорошо видны человеку извне с незамыленным взглядом. Если вы видите, что вопрос или ответ содержит какие-либо недостатки, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь вносить улучшающие правки, ведь содержимое сайта является достоянием всего сообщества, именно мы сами ответственны за качество нашей общей базы знаний. Даже небольшое улучшение, позволяющие оптимизировать содержимое для прочтения, казалось бы, на несколько секунд, в результате приводит к десяткам спасенных человеко-часов.
3. **Обучать культуре и правилам сообщества новых пользователей.** Сегодня на Stack Overflow на русском каждый день регистрируется порядка ста новых пользователей. С большой вероятностью общение на сайте для них - это погружение в совершенно новую культурную среду. Новые пользователи, в данном случае, подобны людям, которые начинают изучать иностранный язык. Они могут правильно понять, но, попробовав сказать что-то, то и дело ошибаются. Плохо подготовленные преподаватели поступают очень опрометчиво, игнорируя ошибки изучающего или, что хуже, критикуя его. Как и преподаватели языка, мы, сообщество, не должны оставлять подобное без внимания или проявлять грубость (а также удалять публикаций без объяснения причин удаления и шагов по улучшению сообщения). Терпением, отзывчивостью и своими знаниями мы завоюем сердца даже самых заядлых нарушителей правил правописания. Если вы видите, что вопрос или ответ не соответствует стандартам качества проекта, не спешите закрывать вкладку обозревателя или измываться над автором. Вместо этого, пожалуйста, объясните пользователю, *в чем конкретно его проблема*, а также *какие шаги необходимо сделать*, чтобы исправить ситуацию. Если же вы не видите способов улучшить сообщение, используйте инструменты сайта: голос против, тревога, закрытие вопроса, заявляя коллегам о проблеме таким образом. И, скорее всего, кто-либо из них сможет найти выход из положения.

Пожалуйста, делитесь не только знаниями, но и культурой общения! Ведь именно этих двух атрибутов так не хватает современному Рунету!

---

Дополнительная публикация [Коллективная правка — залог качественного содержимого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420/)

Comment: `Культура нашего сообщества не просто шокирует новичков, она сбивает их с толку, становясь преградой для получения необходимых знаний. Причина ясна - пользователи, незнакомые со Stack Overflow на русском, просто не привыкли к цивилизованному профессиональному общению по делу на русском языке. ` - тут противоречие какое-то. Все-таки культура нашего сообщества (ru.so) помогает или мешает получать знания?