# В чем проблема одинаковых вопросов на разных ресурсах?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, правила

Буквально вчера [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) удалил мой вопрос с комментарием

> Если вы будете заниматься публикацией одинакового вопроса на многих сайтах, как минимум со Stack Overflow на русском все будет удаляться. Мы стремимся к идеи единого источника знаний. –

Ну да, я запостил тот же вопрос на Тостере. Но никогда ж не знаешь, где выстрелит. И помню какой-то вопрос тоже задал там и там. На тостере в ходе рассуждения нашли ответ сообщя, а на стэке даж не суетнулись. Я и скинул на стэк ответ с тостера. И смотрю, кто-то поставил плюсик, значит ответ был нужен. Зачем отрезать толковые вопросы только потому, что они на разных ресурсах (по секрету скажу, я еще и на нескольких форумах сижу)

---

UPDATE
Как вижу из ответа Николаса - он предпологает что SO.RU в одночайсе стал единственным достоверным ресурсом в сети. А вот сообщество вроде как за свободу информации. Не будем задаваться вопросами патентов, кросс-постинга и иже с ними.

Если я хочу получить ответ, я хочу получить его быстро.

Из недавнего - задал один и тот же вопрос на тостере и SO. На тостере получил ответ за 15 что ли минут.
Вот он https://toster.ru/q/216742
На стэке ответов не было. Я скопировал ответ с тостера. 
Вот он [Postgres сумма за разные интервалы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423788/postgres-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B/423791#423791)

Кто выиграл в этой ситуации? Все. Если кому то понадобится ответ (а по плюсику могу судить что может уже и понадобился), он найдет его и на SO, и на тостере (а может и на форуме Постгрес, если его кто-то скопирует)

Comment: Относительно апдейта: если ответ стал доступнее — это хорошо, конечно. (С перекрёстными ссылками в обе стороны было бы ещё лучше, как по мне.) Но, к сожалению, таким же образом скопировать *чужой* ответ с Тостера нельзя, потому что контент на нём не распространяется под открытой лицензией. Меня даже CC BY-SA на SO не устраивает, у меня в профиле явно указано ещё более либеральное распространение *моего* контента. И это важно, во многих компаниях, особенно зарубежных, с огромной осторожностью обращаются с лицензиями.

Comment: @Discord, а мне плевать какие где лицензии. Я бы скопировал точно так же. Я вообще не понимаю, к чему морочить себе голову с лицензиями на общественных площадках.

Comment: @ixSci Вам-то плевать, но ответ из-за этого уже реально может быть удалён, и тут никаких претензий и обсуждений не будет, потому что закон (и где-то в правилах это явно упомянуто, вроде).

Comment: @Discord, какой такой закон? А где суд? Самоуправство? Значит администрация не права. То, что ты нарушил копирайт нужно доказать, без доказательств о каком законе говорить? Бред все эти лицензии, что начали пихать на форумах. Не было их раньше и все жили нормально, а теперь начали пургой заниматься. Вот уж воистину "Заставь дурака Богу молиться..."

Comment: @ixSci Лицензии были "бредом" во времена пиратских дисков на рынках, а сейчас они часть цивилизованной жизни. Если вы до сих пор не имеете лицензионного софта на компьютере, потому что "а нафига? где суд? самоуправство!", то это не значит, что всем остальным в той же мере покласть на закон.

Comment: @Discord, причём тут софт? У меня весь софт лицензионный уже много лет. Вы действительно не видите разницы между софтом и постом на форуме? Я могу понять, когда люди лицензирует ту информацию, что они плодят в своих блогах, но лицензировать информацию на форумах это выше моего понимания. Тем более, что доказать нарушение лицензии, в таком случае, практически невозможно, т.к. первичность появления ответа на том или ином ресурсе доказать не представляется возможным.

Comment: @Discord, закон подразумевает СУД. Честный, справедливый с возможностью защиты. Удаление постов администрацией никакого отношения к законам не имеет. Здесь администрация является законодательной, судебной и исполнительной властью, что есть абсолютный бред, если пытаться в таком контексте говорить о правах. Это типичная тоталитарная позиция. Поэтому не надо пытаться сравнивать это с "реальной" жизнью. С софтом и прочим. Это другой мир.

Comment: @ixSci Закон подразумевает соблюдение закона. Суд — это обработка исключительных ситуаций. Законы реальной жизни активно применяются и в Интернете, тут не анархия. / Удаление постов по желанию левой пятки администрации сюда не примешивайте, я говорю про соблюдение лицензий — совершенно понятную, формально оформленную в виде законов вещь. Нарушение лицензии на текст и ссылки на торренты с пиратским контентом запрещены по одной и той же причине. СО — это не место, где вы можете остаивать свои идеи инфоанархизма, здесь есть свои правила.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23859/discussion-between-ixsci-and-discord).

Comment: Автор вопроса, Вы абсолютно правы. Я советую потрудится, перевести вопрос на английский и задать его на [Meta StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), я уверен ответы Вас приятно удивят. Если Вы решитесь за это, будьте добры ссылку на вопрос.

Comment: думаю там so естественный монополист. единственно что узкоспециализированные форумы могут дать более качественный ответ

Comment: @des1roer, вчера я не выдержал и со ссылкой на Ваш вопрос задал его на большом SO. С горем пополам, я сумел обяснить в чём проблема. Всё свелось к тому, что кросс-постинг - некрасиво и есть доказательства ухудшения эффективности. Но о запрете, удалении речь вообще не шла. Принятый ответ подробно это раскрывает. Жаль администрация проигнорировала, даже при прямом обращении. Это ясно, им во вред говорить: "это не запрещено".[Ссылка на вопрос](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295475/cross-posting-by-user-and-removed-question-by-moderator-on-so-in-russian-does-o), если будет интересно.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Действительно, с чего такие жёсткие правила? Ни разу у меня такого на большом SO не было. Размещал вопросы там и на форумах MSDN, о чём явно указывал в вопросе. Никто и никогда мне ничего за это не говорил. Считаю, что в данном случае администрация не права в корне и не должна трогать подобные вопросы/ответы.

Comment: Ни у кого не было претензий, потому что вы сообщали о кросс-постинге. А des1roer молча копипастит текст.

Comment: des1roer - автор текста. он может его хоть копипастить, хоть на туалетной бумаге распечатывать - это его право. Он принес ответ с тостера, а не просто бросил вопрос без ответа - и это вполне достойно уважения. Но никак не удаления вопроса.

Comment: @PashaPash "Имеет *юридическое* право" — это ещё не значит, что он имеет право так делать на СО (правила сайта никто не отменял), или что он соблюдает общепринятые правила приличия (сетикет, все дела). Если кросс-ссылки не запрещены больными на голову хозяевами сайта, то ссылки при кросс-постинге, как правило — часть принятого поведения.

Comment: @Discord в вопросах запрещено все, что не имеет прямого отношения к сути вопроса. Даже "привет!" вырезают.Так что как раз ссылка при кросспосте запрещена правилами этого сайта. А вот сам кросспост как раз не запрещен - и то, что факто кросспоста кому-то *лично* не нравится - это проблема этого *кого-то*, а никак не причина для удаления.

Comment: @PashaPash Не говорите глупостей. "Привет" не несёт вообще никакой полезной нагрузки. Ссылка на аналогичный вопрос на другом ресурсе — это важная информация, и её не надо удалять. Нет таких правил на сайте, это исключительно ваши фантазии.

Answer (score 5):

Когда вы постите вопрос, сразу несколько пользователей начинает писать и искать ответ. Ответы принято давать детальные, качественные и по делу. Это отнимает время, а время — деньги.

Отправляя свой вопрос на несколько сайтов, вы поступаете по-свински по отношению к тем, кто хочет вам помочь. Вы тратите их время впустую. Если вам пять минут назад дали ответ на одном ресурсе, то заставлять всех работать впустую на другом ресурсе — это свинство.

Хотите заниматься кросс-постингом — извольте давать ссылки в обе стороны на обоих ресурсах. (И да, скорее всего, на тостере вас за это забанят. `:-)` ) Проявите уважение к авторам ответов. Если вообще делать по-хорошему, то постите вопросы с задержкой, например в день, тогда у вас будет возможность сказать: *"Я запостил этот вопрос на Тостере, вот ссылка, я не получил нужного ответа..."*

Качественный кросс-постинг помогает развитию обоих сообществ. Скрытый кросс-постинг заставляет множество пользователей убивать время впустую.

Ну и постоянная копипаста с ресурса на ресурс — это свинство по отношению к самому ресурсу тоже, потому что поисковики не любят дублированный контент. Для ресурса масштаба Stack Overflow это вряд ли имеет большое значение, но для мелких ресурсов это может быть очень важно. Копипаста без ссылок — зло. Это Интернет, здесь принято связывать ресурсы ссылками.

См. пост на MSE: [Why is cross-posting wrong (on an external site)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141823/152967)

Comment: Дурацкий подход. Реально отталкивает от таких "ресурсов".

Comment: @avp То есть вы за кросс-постинг без раскрытия информации о кросс-постинге?

Comment: Ну не знаю, я не вижу тут неуважения. На многих ресурсах запрещают ссылаться на другие, а значит вынуждают человека делать это втихомолку. Если человек получил ответ на одном ресурсе, но не поделился на другом = это свинство, в остальном я не вижу проблемы. Человеку главное найти ответ на вопрос, а не куртуазность выказывать.

Comment: Отвечая на вопрос, опять же, я трачу своё время и это исключительно моя проблема. Задающего вопрос мои проблемы интересовать не должны. так же как меня мало интересуют проблемы задающего. Ответы дело добровольное.

Comment: @ixSci У разных ресурсов и сообществ разные традиции. Если хозяева ресурса трясутся над траффиком и боятся, что кто-то уйдёт к конкурентам — это одно, тогда приходится кросс-постить молча. А если хозяева ресурсов за свободное распространение информации (на SE весь текстовый контент — CC BY-SA 3.0), за полноценный Интернет, и не боятся "потерять" траффик  — это другое, и нужно следовать порядкам этого ресурса. / Исторически, кросс-постинг вообще мало где любят. Не знаю, почему у вас сложилось альтернативное мнение. / И я не нашёл лицензию на текст Тостера. Вроде, Николас говорил, что там не ОК.

Comment: Т.е. Ваше предложение - просто указывать в вопросе ссылки на все ресурсы, где вопрос был задан? В целом, я считаю, что это разумно и не обременяет пользователя сверх меры. Но нужно тогда добавить это в правила, которыми можно в нос тыкать.

Comment: Обратных ссылок(тостер->so) мы требовать не вправе, тем не менее. Это уже пусть будет заботой других ресурсов(того же тостера)

Comment: @ixSci В целом да, ссылки достаточно, как по мне. Если кто-то пришёл из Гугла, то ему будет легче найти информацию. Если кто-то отвечает, то он может сэкономить время, если на другом ресурсе уже дан ответ. Да и самому автору вопроса будет удобнее переходить между ответами на разных ресурсах. Ну и к такому выводу пришли на МСЕ, вопрос там хорошо заплюсован — хороший признак (не могу посмотреть минусы, к сожалению — репы мало). / Что касается конкретно Тостера, то надо прояснить вопрос с лицензиями... Хабр, например, при определённых условиях захавывает права на контент.

Comment: Я за удобство обмена информацией и против надуманных ограничений (включая так называемое *авторское право*, *патенты* и т.п.)

Comment: @avp Я, конечно, поддерживаю свободу информации, но инфоанархизм — это уж слишком радикально, в современном обществе рационально придерживаться каких-то рамок, по-другому оно существовать не может. Ну и моё мнение в первую очередь касается *удобства* навигации и *раскрытия всей информации*, поэтому не думаю, что я так уж сильно противоречу вашим взглядам.

Comment: "Я запостил этот вопрос на Тостере, вот ссылка, я не получил нужного ответа..." - это удалит первый же редактор, вместе с "добрый день".

Comment: @PashaPash Не должен, это важная информация.

Comment: @Discord это информация не имеющая отношения к сути вопроса. ее вырежут. в том числе, и потому, что это ссылка на ресурс-конкурент.

Comment: @PashaPash: Не следует удалять ссылки на дополнительную информацию, относящуюся к вопросу. Хотя идеально, автор вопроса должен сам описать *прямо в вопросе* уже опробованные подходы из опубликованных ответов и почему они для него не сработали. И не хорошо, удаляя ссылку, маскировать, что вопрос является кросс-постом.

Comment: @jfs лично я бы не стал трогать ссылки на кросспост, но тут встречаются радикалы. Суть проблемы в том, что поводом для удаления вопроса послужил не сам факт кросспоста, а именно ссылка на копию. А [если без ссылки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419502/) - то можно хоть [на сайте для фрилансеров кросспостить](https://www.fl.ru/projects/2286894/).

Comment: @PashaPash Если вы видите радикалов, которые удаляют из поста релевантные ссылки, то, пожалуйста, сообщайте об этом. (Если власть имущие *удаляют вопросы* — это уже другая история...) / Вопрос "Сценарии/скрипты для работы в браузере" уже обсудили на Мете (см. пост Qwertiy), и его уже пытались закрыть, но отдельным юзерам захотелось переделать идею вопроса и написать ответ на то, чего ОП не спрашивал. Этот вопрос не соответствует правилам и должен был быть удалён — независимо от того, кросс-пост это или нет. Но это моё ИМНХО, с которым сообщество не согласилось.

Comment: @Discord лично для меня вывод из всех этой шумихи - хочешь кросспостить - делай это втихаря!

Comment: @PashaPash Если случаи единичные, то каких-то особых проблем не вижу: один-другой вопрос — это статистическая погрешность. А если кросс-постить каждый вопрос, то это таки заметят. И это может спровоцировать отдельных юзеров, включая меня, *с особой тщательностью* следить за постами юзера.

Comment: @PashaPash Удаленный вопрос не содержал ссылки на какие-либо ресурсы. Более того, мы никогда не удаляем ссылки на ресурсы (и вопросы с такими ссылками), если информация по ссылке имеет отношение к вопросу.

Comment: @Discord, Вы так говорите про "свинство", можно подумать как новый вопрос появляется, то все бегут на него отвечать и получают приличну сумму денег за это. Даже если человек, задавший вопрос, уже нашёл ответ, это не запрещает ответчику предложить свой ответ. Если он хороший - сообщество проголосует. А принятый ответ - это уже дело сугубо личное для задающего.

Comment: @Yurets Именно, что все бегут. Посмотрите, какая конкуренция на популярные метки.

Comment: @Discord, ну это ж не говорит о том, что это впустую потраченное время. SO ориентирован не на юзера, а на контент, или я не прав? Нашёл ли юзер ответ тут или на форуме, главное, что хорошие ответы были даны.

Comment: @Yurets Если вам нравится тратить время на то, что не нужно никому, включая вас и автора вопроса, то это ваше право. А я здесь выражаю мнение тех, кто предпочитает заниматься полезными делами, а не бесполезными. Постить ответ-дубль — бесполезно.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что проблемы дублированных на разных ресурсах вопросов, как таковой нет, особенно в изложении уважаемого [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky). Любой человек вправе искать решение проблемы любым доступным ему способом, несколько жестоко пытаться мешать ему решить проблему.

Насчет того, что кто-то начинает искать решение проблемы через общепоисковые ресурсы и сталкивается с множеством дублей без решения или с множеством решений без видимой отметки качества этого решения, то думаю, что проблема надумана.

Я не знаю много именно программистов, которые бы искали решение через тот же гугл или яндекс, все они знают, где есть решение - если некоторому коллеге-программисту захочется качественного заревизированного решения, он будет искать его, используя поиск самого StackOverflow, получая замечательные проверенные исключительно грамотные ответы лучших из программистов :) - и скорее всего получит основной вектор решения своего затруднения, ибо на SO редко можно встретить всеобъемлющий ответ, который требует большого количества букв , однако часто требуется более расширенная информация по проблеме: более детальное описание, полный сэмпл кода, альтернативное решение, в конце концов и нет ничего зазорного, что человек прочитает потом хоть и кучу мусора - возможно и что то ценное получит.
Если брать новичков, то такова их нелегкая доля - набивать шишки, его время - это его время, ему решать, сколько его затратить на решение проблемы и сколько некачественных ответов перед этим перечитать. В конце концов придет опыт быстрого поиска верного решения, но не через навязывание эксклюзивного содержимого, от такого подхода будет только хуже.

Начет неуважения при кросс-постинге это уже вообще слишком .. если вы знаете решение - поделитесь им, это не займет у вас много душевных сил и времени - в общем то вы решение дарите - делать это надо легко и свободно - никто не обязывает вас отвечать, как никто и не обязан вам за ваш ответ. Ведь вы и здесь не один, как правило, отвечаете на вопрос (получается по выше озвученной логике, кто ответил первым - тот не зря клаву портил - остальные впустую старались), что на другом ресурсе ответят - от того, что вы дадите грамотный, развернутый и компетентный ответ всем будет только лучше, даже если он частично продублирован - абсолютно одинаковых решений, как правило, не бывает, если это не дилетанский вопрос новичка по элементарным основам.
Что с того, что кто то еще где то в другом месте ответит на такой же вопрос - кто то прочитает там, кто то здесь - одни люди посещают одни ресурсы , другие - другие, третьи оба .. не знаю, какая в этом проблема.

МСЛМ естественно без претензии на истину в последней инстанции :)

Comment: Как мне распоряжаться своим временем — это решаю я сам. И для этого решения перекрёстные ссылки важны, даже если вам на них наплевать. Я не могу понять, почему кто-то вообще выступает против перекрёстных ссылок — **вредят-то они как?!** Это добавление *удобства* и проявление *уважения*, автор поста от добавления лишнего параграфа не умрёт.

Comment: @Discord ссылка выдает факт кросспоста -> пост удаляется. [нет ссылки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419502/) - [нет проблем](https://www.fl.ru/projects/2286894/).

Comment: @PashaPash Можете привести примеры удалённых постов? ОП не привёл ссылки на удалённые вопросы, а искать по удалёным вопросам могут только ромбы и выше. / Подход Николаса к удалению постов я буду готов обсуждать, когда он приведёт мнение остальных сотрудников SE. Я попросил в чате спросить их, и он сказал, что спросит. Исходя из этой информации, уже можно будет рассуждать об административных нюансах. Свой же ответ писал, оценивая исключительно своё мнение как пишущего ответы на вопросы — что мне и, как мне думается, остальным участникам будет удобно и полезно.

Comment: @Discord топикастер заявил об удалении вопроса, Николас не опроверг - значит факт удаления был. Спрашивайте у них. В подтверждение подхода "нет ссылки-нет проблем" могу привести [вот этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424430/) - он прямо сейчас висит на главной. Это кросспост с тостера, причем автор сам нашел решение и отписался о нем. Но только на тостере. И, как видно, никто не спешит вопрос удалять с SO.

Comment: @PashaPash Ну вот сейчас и проверим, что будет. :)

Comment: @Discord кто-нибудь в погоне за кармой скопипастит ответ, какие тут еще могут быть варианты

Comment: Раз уж вы, парни, выбрали мой ответ для общения между собой :) и коменты прилетают и мне в ящик, то вот вам еще кросс-пост - давайте следить и за его судьбой: [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424419/Алгоритм-для-определения-шагов-с-помощью-акселерометра) - [там](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=665025)

Comment: @pavlofff )) по первому вопросу результат был внезапен - автор откатил правку со ссылкой на тостер! - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/424430/revisions

Comment: @pavlofff С этим вопросом всё просто, он тут оффтопик. Хотя в принципе можно выбросить просьбу подобрать библиотеку...

Answer (score 0):

У нашего сообщества есть всеобъемлющие цели - то, ради чего мы здесь. Проект призван решить острые проблемы русскоязычного сообщества программистов:

- отсутствие стандарта общения, такого как Stack Overflow для англоязычных коллег;
- отсутствие свободно распространяемой базы прикладных знаний, помогающей решать повседневные задачи на порядок эффективнее.

Как вы видите, одна из важнейших целей, к которой стремиться Stack Overflow на русском - это единый источник знаний.

Представьте, вы столкнулись с проблемой. Обычно, первое решение - это поиск. Вы задаете поисковую фразу, в ответ получаете набор ссылок на разные ресурсы. Ознакомившись с поисковой выдачей, вы понимаете, что все ресурсы содержат один и тот же вопрос, от одного и того же пользователя, и все без реального решения (либо с различными решениями). То есть либо вы потратили пол часа на прочтение тем, в которых нет решения (читай, “зря”), либо нашли множество разных решений, которые теперь надо проверять (на большинстве сайтов нет функции принятия единого ответа или голосования за/против).

Ко всему, каков авторитет сообщества, которое принимает решение о правильности ответа? Авторитет не кажется таким уж и важным, когда вопрос тривиален, но все меняется, например, в вопросах безопасности связанных с базами данных или настройки корпоративной сети?

[Из публикации о коллективной правке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/220/), мы все знаем, что на Stack Overflow на русском...

> … вопросы задаются не только и не столько для пользователей, желающих ответить, а ответы даются не только и не столько для авторов вопросов - они публикуются для тысяч наших коллег, которые в будущем могут столкнуться с аналогичной проблемой. Задача сообщества сделать так, чтобы поиск решения проблемы занимал считанные секунды.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, на сколько публикация одинакового содержимого способствует уменьшению времени решения задач?

Таким образом, в нашем понимании, давая возможность публикации одного и того же вопроса на нескольких сайтах, сообщество теряет то самое единство информации. Как вы могли заметить, мы закрываем вопросы-копии, для того же, чтобы вся информация о конкретной проблеме содержалась лишь в одном месте, даже в рамках одного сайта. Единый источник знаний приводит не только к ускорению поиска, но и более, к постоянному улучшению представленной информации. Участники сообщества, которые обладают знаниями в конкретном вопросе, смогут постоянно вносить улучшающие правки в существующие ответы или добавлять новые, ведь всем будет известно место, где ее можно данную тему.

Теряя единство информации мы также теряем и единство сообщества. Как вы указали, вы не уверены, на каком из сайтов есть тот самый знаток, который поможет вам в решении задачи. Это происходит потому что все привыкли, что в Рунете нет единого стандарта общения, такого как Stack Overflow, а как результат, у нас, русскоязычных разработчиков, нет общности, знатоки разбросаны по многим небольшим ресурсам.

Задача Stack Overflow на русском собрать знатоков воедино. Лишь тогда мы сможем создать единую проверенную свободную базу прикладных решений, а также стандарт общения, который позволит в будущем уменьшить время не только на поиск, но и на публикацию вопросов и ответов.

Чтобы развеять сомнения о получении ответа на ваш вопрос (или подтвердить опасения), пожалуйста, обратитесь к странице участников сообщества, и убедитесь в том, что есть знаток, публикующий ответы на связанные вопросы. Еще во времена ХэшКода, [в сообществе было достаточно участников](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/177/6), чтобы покрыть большую область знаний. Более того, с момента перерождения проекта, к нашему, пока еще растущему “островку знаний”, присоединились уникальные люди, такие как [Discord](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/), [ixSci](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15146/), [PashaPash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177221/) и многие другие.

Уверен, добродетель участников сообщества Stack Overflow на русском, а также свод правил, которые мы вместе вырабатываем, поможет изменить представление и способы общения русскоязычных разработчиков на нашем родном языке, а как результат, улучшить производительность и качество труда. Для этого, нам надо следовать этим самым правилам, большинство из которых, ко всему, уже проверены на англоязычной аудитории.

Таким образом, пожалуйста, публикуйте ваши вопросы в единственном виде. Если время ожидания ответа, по вашему мнению, затягивается, убедитесь, что вы качественно оформили вопрос и смысл его понятен каждому. В дополнении, вы можете пригласить ваших коллег и друзей принять участие в сообществе, таким образом, вы поможете не только себе, но и многим другим пользователям, задающим связанные вопросы.

Comment: Единый стандарт общения это как единый учебник истории? Nicolas, мне кажется Вас заносит. Никаким единым стандартом русский SO не является и являться не будет. Как не является им SO английский. Да, это наиболее популярный сайт среди англоязычных программистов, но он далеко не единственный. И когда мне надо задать вопрос по libvlc я иду на форму vlc(могу запостить вопрос на SO тоже) потому что меня интересует ответ на вопрос, в максимально сжатые сроки. Наибольшая вероятность получить ответ по специфичным проблемам - посетить соответствующий форум. Но продублировать вопрос на SO тоже полезно.

Comment: Не нужно пытаться насильственно делать SO пупом рунета для программистов, я считаю, что репрессии в данном вопросе совершенно избыточны и даже вредны. Выставляя себя в позицию: "либо ты у нас постишь, либо идёшь на ***" контр-продуктивны и будут только отпугивать пользователей. Ещё раз повторюсь, не надо из SO делать икону. Если у человека вопрос по Qt, ffmpeg, libvlc и т.п. у него куда больше шанс получить ответ на соответствующем форуме, чем на SO. Это я говорю из своего опыта. Форумы разные нужны, форумы разные важны.

Comment: На мой взгляд, ограничения, которые предложил @Discord, являются наиболее приемлемыми. Большие ограничения могут вылиться лишь в отток пользователей, я не вижу как эти ограничения могут помочь развитию ресурса.

Comment: @ixSci В прямо-таки отток юзеров я не очень верю, потому что на СО красными буквами не написано, что кросс-постить нельзя. На это ограничение надо ещё умудриться наткнуться, причём несколько раз, как ОП (ну а Мету вообще читает статистическая погрешность). Но в целом я с вами согласен, подобные правила звучат излишне радикально, особенно в свете того, что SO.RU намерен оттягивать юзеров SO.EN, а какое-то время назад Google стал менее активно проталкивать SO.EN в результаты запросов. [Тж. см. чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21671270#21671270), ждём подробностей.

Comment: `Как вы видите, одна из важнейших целей, к которой стремиться Stack Overflow на русском - это единый источник знаний.` - у вас тут логика хромает. Нет и не может быть цели стать единым и тем более единственным источником знаний. Тогда уж следует начать с того, что запретить википедию на русском.

Comment: @NickVolynkin На мой взгляд, ваше утверждение про Википедию не верно. Википедия является уникальным  источником энциклопедических знаний. Stack Overflow на русском решает проблему накопления прикладных знаний. Проекты разные. Они дополняют друг друга.

Comment: @ixSci Единый учебник пишется одним автором (в этом и есть его проблема, которую, как мне кажется, вы хотите подчеркнуть). Stack Overflow редактируется множеством авторов. Сравнение, на мой взгляд не корректное.

Comment: @ixSci Публикуя вопрос на специализированном форуме поддержки, мы, на мой взгляд, [отходим от вопроса к сообществу, к вопросу к коллегам](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/271/). Такой способ, как вы верно отметили, позволяет решить задачу быстрее, так как знания сосредоточены среди сообщества, к которому вы обращаетесь.

Comment: @ixSci Публикуя, в дальнейшем, ваш вопрос и его решение на Stack Overflow (за что вам отдельное большое спасибо) вы помогаете всем тем, кто столкнется с подобной задачей в будущем, так как движок SO построен вокруг идеи кристаллизации знаний, а форумы поддержки, в большей массе, работают на устаревшем ПО, предназначенным для дискуссий.

Comment: Считаю Ваш ответ не актуальным. Ваша позиция стоит на "уникальности" SO как ресурса, но если задуматься, то больше 50% ответов УЖЕ приходит на SO из других ресурсов. Как с этим будем бороться, прогонять через Advego Plagiatus?