# Коллективная правка — залог качественного содержимого

Tags: поддержка, faq

Сообщество Stack Overflow на русском открыто для всех, кто любит и ценит программирование и системное администрирование, независимо от той степени профессионального мастерства, которой достиг участник сообщества. Как следствие, вопросы очень сильно различаются по своей содержательности, качеству и оформлению. Хоть вопросы могут быть любыми по сложности, но все они должны соответствовать критерию качества.

Уметь задавать качественный вопрос — это особое искусство, которое достигается с практикой. Можно провести аналогию с программным кодом: новички не сразу проходят ревью кода по большей части не потому, что их код неверно решает задачу, а потому, что в оформлении допущена ошибка. Опытные коллеги обычно подсказывают, что и как следует изменить, внося свои правки и комментарии. Более того, широко распространена практика, когда инженерам выделяют время для улучшения читаемости уже написанного работающего кода.

Stack Overflow на русском является объединением вики-энциклопедии, коллективного блога, ленты новостей и форума. Коллективная правка, черты вики-энциклопедии означают, что любой пользователь может улучшить любое сообщение. Высокое качество содержимого, аккуратность и выразительность в оформлении вопросов и ответов критически необходимы, поскольку содержимое нацелено на многократное прочтение (точно так же, как программный код, который поддерживают десятилетиями).

При общении в сообществе мы рекомендуем придерживаться ряда правил.

- Заголовок сообщения следует начинать с большой буквы и оканчивать либо вопросительным знаком (если заголовок содержит вопрос), либо отсутствием знака препинания вообще.
- Текст сообщений представлять простым русским литературным языком.
- Абзацы в тексте разделять пустой строкой (в редакторе MarkDown это два перевода строки).
- Прямые цитаты, сообщения об ошибках, отрывки логов оформлять как цитаты (символ `>`).
- Код программ или скриптов добавлять отдельным абзацем.
- Для форматирования кода использовать общепринятый стиль кодирования, например, для программ на C под Linux: `indent -linux code.c`.
- Оформлять ссылки как прямые, с осмысленным названием (например, [сообщество программистов и системных администраторов Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)).

Все эти простые правила во многом способствуют тому, что сообщение, оставленное участником сообщества, будет полезно многим другим коллегам в будущем.

На ранних стадиях развития Stack Overflow на русском в сообществе имела место редакция тем командой модераторов. Корректорская правка жизненно необходима для создания и поддержания высокой культуры общения. В то же время мы полагаем, что редакция командой модераторов — это вынужденная мера, которую следует сводить к минимуму.

**Сообщество имеет право и должно самостоятельно управлять своим содержимым.**

Редактируя вопросы, ответы и комментарии в сообществе, вы не просто делаете тему легко читаемой, вы вводите стандарты создания содержимого и, более того, обучаете других пользователей этим стандартам, что вкупе позволяет сделать уникальный источник знаний, помогающий в ежедневной профессиональной деятельности многим людям.

Для улучшения Stack Overflow на русском, как источника свободно распространяемых знаний, обращайте внимание, а при необходимости корректируйте:

- заголовок вопроса;
- метки вопроса;
- синтаксические и орфографические ошибки;
- форматирование сообщений;
- оформление сообщений.

**Культура общения на форуме в большей степени зависит от сообщества, чем от модераторов.**

Мы полагаем, что сейчас на Stack Overflow на русском есть большое количество талантливых образованных специалистов, которые являются опорой и примером для сообщества.

Если вы видите, что кто–то допустил ошибку в правописании, оформлении или попросту не смог подобрать нужных слов для выражения своей мысли в вопросе или ответе, не стесняйтесь редактировать, модифицировать и улучшать. Мы сами ответственны за нашу базу знаний!

---

Дополнительная публикация: [Коллективная правка содержимого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/220/)

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Когда стоит использовать внутристрочное выделение для кода?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)