# Являются ли правки пользователя Regent вредными?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, правки

Как мне кажется, пользователь [Regent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183458/regent) вносит слишком много правок. Возможно он делает это исключительно для кармы?

У меня произошел неприятный инцидент: я откатил его изменения - он тупо поставил минус посту. Причем даже не по своей тематике (мой пост был в разделе шарпа, его же тематика - яваскрипт). Планирует ли администрация ограничивать подобные действия? Какие меры будут применяться?

p.s. я всегда считал что карма должна зарабатываться достойно, грамотными и подробными ответами на вопросы. Почти все новые вопросы уже кем то отредактированы, хотя большинство из них изначально были корректными. За что им повышать карму? За знание русского языка? Тогда пусть идут на ресурсы, специализирующиеся на нем - и там показывают свою грамотность.

Comment: @z668, не нужно всё так близко к сердцу воспринимать. К тому же, с чего Вы взяли, что минус именно он влепил?

Comment: Не стоит переживать за рейтинги (особенно чужие). Мы же тут не ради циферок.

Comment: @Nofate, на данный момент именно так. Идет соперничество за повышение собственного рейтинга. Взгляните на ситуацию шире.

Comment: @ixSci, логика проста: глубокая ночь по МСК, делаю откат изменений, спустя несколько минут - минус посту.

Comment: Относитесь проще к этому. Возможность редактирования чужих вопросов и ответов это очень мощный инструмент, но в основном им пользуются для адекватных правок. Иногда случается, что какой-нибудь тролль начинает делать всякую фигню, но потом он быстро отправляется в бан, а все его труды откатываются. Не воспринимайте правку как укол лично против Вас- это просто улучшение качества контента во всем сообществе. За такое надо говорить «спасибо» :-)

Comment: @ReinRaus, да как бы не столько раздражает сама правка, сколько минус посту после отката мною этой правки. За что в таком случае говорить спасибо?

Comment: @z668 Пожалуйста, подскажите, про какой именно вопрос идёт речь?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433582/bitmap-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA

Comment: Уважаемый @z668, вы до такой степени не правы, написав это сообщение, да еще и в настолько оскорбительном тоне,  что становится грустно, что кто-то думает такие нехорошие мысли про человека, который старается сделать этот ресурс немного лучше,тратя свое время и при этом абсолютно безвозмездно - за самостоятельные правки никакой "крамы" не дают, вы и сами, с вашей "крамой" должны бы знать это.

Comment: @pavlofff, ладно, хорошо. Но зачем тогда ставить минус моему вопросу, после того как я откатил его правку? Это нормально? Это адекватно? Что после этого прикажете думать про этого человека?

Comment: Почему все, кто отписался в теме - накинулись на меня за откат правки, и просто проигнорировали!! минус моему посту - когда я эту правку откатил. Пост нормальны, читабельный, понятный. Отвечающим в комментариях объяснил что мне нужен общий алгоритм действий. У вас какое то однобокое суждение, которое в упор не хочет видеть другую сторону вопроса.

Comment: @z668 даже если минус поставил и он, то вполне заслужено. Вы откатили корретную правку, сделав все опять гораздо хуже. Вот это как раз ненормально и неадекватно. В общем то как вы и сами видите из этого обсуждения - никто не разделяет вашу точку зрения.

Comment: @All, ну чтож, все предельно ясно. Пойду на кибер, там люди адекватнее. Такое ощущение, что в этом треде собрались закоренелые сишники, не приемлющие ничего, кроме своей точки зрения.

Comment: А с сишниками-то что не так? Кто угодно может поставить кому угодно минус просто потому что захотелось. Не обсуждать же каждый такой случай?

Comment: @z668, накинулись на вас не за откат правки, а за не слишком обоснованные обвинения (и даже оскорбления) в адрес другого участника.

Comment: @z668, думаю хорошим окончанием данной дискуссии будет извиниться перед Regent и удалить вопрос.

Comment: @Nofate, думаю лучшим для меня окончанием этой дискуссии будет простой покинуть SO. С текущими правилами, установленными на данном сайте - он меня в корне не устраивает. Regent получил то, что действительно заслуживает. Это мое мнение о данном человеке, ни о каких извинениях не может идти и речи.

Comment: @z668 К сожалению не успел ответить. Nofate, NickVolynkin и pavlofff совершенно правы. Внесенные изменения были полезны. Голосование на то и нужно, чтобы выражать свое мнение. Голос против означает, что с вопросом что-то не так: не понятен, не интересен, плохо оформлен. Не совсем понятно, в чем поведение участника вышло за рамки. Regent сделал более чем нужно - он не просто поставил вам минус или проголосовал за закрытие, он  потратил сове время, чтобы сделать ваш вопрос лучше, как результат, повысил вероятность получения ответа.

Comment: @z668 На Stack Overflow на русском мы не просто помогаем друг другу ответами, мы создаем свободно распространяемую базу прикладных решений. Чтобы упростить чтение вопросов коллегам, которые попадут на сайт их поисковика, на Stack Overflow на русском следует поддерживать как можно более литературный язык общения. Regent не раз поправлял меня как в контексте правил языка, так и в вопросах принятия решения о закрытии тем, за что я ему крайне благодарен. Мы все допускаем ошибки.

Comment: @z668 Конечно, крайне неприятно, когда мы делимся своей проблемой с сообществом, а в ответ получаем критику. Но в случае конструктивной критики, и более, помощи от энтузиастов, как мне кажется, мы должны быть благодарны им за то, что помимо профессиональных знаний они позволяют нам расширить наш кругозор: выучить новое правило правописания, перенять новый подход к публикации вопросов и т. д. Уверен, посмотрев на проблему с этой стороны, вместо критики, вы захотите выразить Regent благодарность за все то, что он делает.

Comment: @Regent Всегда приятней читать грамотный текст, чем поток сознания. Если какой-то парень тратит свое время, чтобы вопросы других звучали более гармонично - спасибо за это.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Если вы про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/433582/2, то это вполне приемлемая правка. А вот откат полезных правок - это, напротив, вандализм.

Напомню, что все участники сообщества в равной степени имеют возможности улучшения существующих вопросов и ответов. Участвуя на сайтах сети StackExchange вы соглашаетесь с этим пунктом из [пользовательского соглашения](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#3SubscriberContent):

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.

То есть, нажимая кнопку "Отправить вопрос" вы передаете текст сообществу на правах лицензии [CC-BY-SA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_Creative_Commons).

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда отвечу вашими же словами - у меня есть возможность откатить изменения и я ею воспользовался. Что разрешено - то не запрещено.

Comment: @z668 рекомендую перечитывать строку про вандализм до полного понимания.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в данном случае я не нарушил никаких правил откатывая изменения. Про вандализм - это конечно огромное преувеличение.

Comment: Конечно, есть возможность. Как и окружающих - не одобрить откат.

Comment: @Nofate, конечно. Но в конце концов можно и удалить вопрос, и открыть его по новому - переформулировав вопрос. И все это не нарушит правил сообщества. Этот хоровод может длиться долго.

Comment: @z668 такой хоровод быстро пересекается сообществом и модераторами.

Answer (score 22):

[Репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), а не карма и не крама.

Репутация дается только за [проверяемые правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing). При достижении уровня репутации 1000 дается [привилегия делать правки без проверки другими участниками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), а репутация больше не дается.

Regent давно преодолел порог в 1000 репутации и не получает ее за правки.

> каждый ... может редактировать посты.

Если убрать оскорбления, то такова модель работы StackOverflow. Содержимое сайта улучшается путем [коллективной правки содержимого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/220/), цель которой [улучшать это самое содержимое](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420/), как ни странно.

В частности, [правка Regent'а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/433582/revisions) была верной:

1. Убрал метку из заголовка
2. Добавил метку туда, где должны быть метки
3. Поправил стилистику текста
4. Поправил неизвестную единицу измерения `мб` на [мегабайты, `МБ`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)

> большинство из них изначально были корректными.

Это просто неправда. В том числе ваш не был корректным.

1. Вам задали уточняющие вопросы, а вы их проигнорировали.
2. Сделали правку, повышающую качество вопроса, а вы ее откатили.
3. Вероятно еще и отметят "требующим правки", и вы сможете прочитать там детальное объяснение.

> За знание русского языка?

Которое является одним из важных навыков IT-специалиста. Тексты ваших вопросов и ответов будут прочитаны еще сотни, а то и тысячи раз. Пользователям будет приятно читать грамотно написанный текст.

Еще одним важным навыком является умение читать документацию. Всех вопросов можно было бы избежать, если прочитать справочные материалы сайта.

Третий важный навык - умение цивилизованно спорить.

Comment: Ну, судя по вашей репутации, вы не далеко от него ушли. Соответственно разделяете его "мировоззрение". По крайней мере глупо лезть туда, где должны выступать не "новички".

Comment: И еще, вы не учли момент, что я сам потом отредактировал свой пост. Да, его закрыли т.к. сама тема очень обширна и включает в себя разные форматы. Но тем не менее нужные мне ответы я получил, за что благодарен тем - кто действительно умеет грамотно отвечать на вопросы, а не редактировать их.

Comment: z688 руки прочь от моего ответа, прекратите вандализм. Хотите ответить - отвечайте в комментариях.

Comment: Ну вот теперь то вы хотябы поняли меня =)

Comment: @z668 Вы удалили фрагменты текста, искажая содержимое поста. Это не то же самое, что исправить ошибки.

Comment: Почему `мб` - неизвестная единица измерения? Это же миллибиты!

Comment: @PavelMayorov о, хороший вариант, в них можно измерять количество полезной информации на рен-тв и прочих подобных каналах.